# When making a calculated column, how do I sum across columns with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe called `df` that looks like this

```
GENDER,CHOCOLATE,VANILLA,...A_BUNCH_OF_COLUMNS_HERE...,ORANGUTAN
M,11,22,...,33
F,22,33,...,44
M,22,11,...,22
F,44,55,...,66
```

I want to make a new column called `PERCENTAGE_ORANGUTAN` which would be calculated as `ORANGUTAN / SUM(previous_columns)`

I know how to make a calculated column with`dplyr` *if I know the names of the columns before `ORANGUTAN`*. But if I know not the names or number of columns before `ORANGUTAN`, how do I calculate `PERCENTAGE_ORANGUTAN`? Or without `dplyr`?

Answer (score 4):

There may be a more "dplyr-ish" idiom, but if you know you want all the columns before the `ORANGUTAN` column, you could use `match` to select them. For example, using the built-in `mtcars` data frame:

```
mtcars %>% 
   mutate(pct = wt/rowSums(.[ , 1:(match("wt", names(.))-1)]))
```

The above code creates a new column called `pct` by dividing the `wt` column by the sum of all the columns preceding it (which is non-sensical and just for illustration).

`.` is a "pronoun" that refers to the `mtcars` data frame.

We want the sum of columns 1 through the column before `wt`. `match` returns the numerical index of `wt` in the vector of column names of `mtcars`. That value happens to be 6, so we subtract 1 from it to get the sum of columns 1 through 5.

Answer (score 0):

In base:

First we will remove all columns that are not numeric:

```
df1 <- df[,sapply(df, is.numeric)]
```

Then subset by those that have an index greater than 'ORANGUTAN', and divide:

```
df$new <- df1$ORANGUTAN / rowSums(df1[ , 1:which(names(df1) == 'ORANGUTAN')])
```

giving:

```
[1] 0.5000000 0.4444444 0.4000000 0.4000000
```

data:

```
df = read.table(text = "GENDER,CHOCOLATE,VANILLA,ORANGUTAN
M,11,22,33
F,22,33,44
M,22,11,22
F,44,55,66", sep = ',', header = TRUE)
```